# converting a S4 object to a matrix type in Rcpp Armadillo

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

In my project in `RcppArmadillo` , I have some matrices (e.g. mat A,B,C;) and also one S4 object, e.g. D (from an external function in R). Since I need to do some calculation between these matrices and D, I want to convert "D" to a suitable data type in `RcppArmadillo`, for instance `arma::mat D` .
Is it possible? And  what is the best way for doing this? 
It is a similar code:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List func1(arma::mat A, arma::mat B){

  // Incoming
  Rcpp::List outcome;
  arma::mat rvecs;
  arma::vec rvals;
   Rcpp::Environment Matrix("package:Matrix"); 
   Rcpp::Function nearPD = Matrix["nearPD"];

 // Computation   
 Rcpp::List PD=nearPD(B);
 Rcpp::S4 D = PD["mat"];
 eig_sym(rvals, rvecs, D);
 arma::mat RI12_hat = rvecs * arma::diagmat(1.0/sqrt(rvals)) * rvecs.t();
  arma::mat diff = A - D;

  // Release results
  outcome = Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("rvals")    = rvals, 
                               Rcpp::Named("RI12_hat") = RI12_hat, 
                               Rcpp::Named("rvecs")    = rvecs);
  return outcome;   
}
```

where D is a matrix of class `dpoMatrix`, the computed positive-definite matrix and the error message is "`no matching for operator`".

Comment: Yes. Please post the code you presently have.

Comment: @coatless I added a simple part of my code.

Comment: you sort of need to specify what the S4 object is... Is it a matrix from the `Matrix` package? Please provide the `dput()` of the `D` object.

Comment: @coatless I add some details to the code. Here the S4 object is a matrix from the Matrix package.

Comment: perhaps not valuable to you today, but this may be generally solved [this summer](https://github.com/rstats-gsoc/gsoc2017/wiki/Sparse-matrix-automatic-conversion-in-RcppArmadillo)

Comment: what's wrong with `arma::sp_mat`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no `as<>()` or `wrap()` for a [`dpoMatrix`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/dpoMatrix-class.html) object yet. However, using the `S4` class, we can extract out the necessary components and reuse the memory using [armadillo's advanced ctor for matrices](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#adv_constructors_mat). First, we must understand the [`dpoMatrix`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/dpoMatrix-class.html) object by either looking at its [documentation for the underlying `Matrix` class](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/Matrix-class.html) or constructing an example.

Consider the following:

```
B <- matrix(1, 3,3); B[1,3] <- B[3,1] <- 0
n.B <- nearPD(B, corr=TRUE, do2eigen=FALSE)
str(n.B)
```

This gives:

```
List of 7
 $ mat        :Formal class 'dpoMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 5 slots
  .. ..@ x       : num [1:9] 1 0.761 0.157 0.761 1 ...
  .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 3 3
  .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..@ uplo    : chr "U"
  .. ..@ factors : list()
 $ eigenvalues: num [1:3] 2.157 0.843 -0.679
 $ corr       : logi TRUE
 $ normF      : num 0.528
 $ iterations : num 18
 $ rel.tol    : num 6.48e-08
 $ converged  : logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "nearPD"
```

Thus, we can retrieve the *values* of the matrix from the `x` slot and the dimensions from the `Dim` slot with `.slot("name_here")` member function.

### Implementation

With that being said, we'll whip up a quick implementation as follows:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List magic_func(arma::mat A, arma::mat B){

  // Incoming
  Rcpp::List outcome;
  arma::mat rvecs;
  arma::vec rvals;
  Rcpp::Environment Matrix("package:Matrix"); // Load the Matrix package in R!
  Rcpp::Function nearPD = Matrix["nearPD"];   // Extract nearPD() R function

  // Compute with R function an S4 object
  Rcpp::List PD = nearPD(B);
  Rcpp::S4 D_s4 = PD["mat"];

  // Convert the S4 object to an Armadillo matrix
  Rcpp::NumericVector temp = Rcpp::NumericVector(D_s4.slot("x"));
  Rcpp::NumericVector dims = D_s4.slot("Dim");

  // Advanced armadillo matrix ctor that reuses memory
  arma::mat D(temp.begin(), // pointer to NumericVector
              dims[0],      // Number of Rows
              dims[1],      // Number of Columns
              false,        // Avoid copying by disabling `copy_aux_mem`
              true);        // Bind memory by enabling `strict`

  // Computation
  eig_sym(rvals, rvecs, D);
  arma::mat RI12_hat = rvecs * arma::diagmat(1.0/sqrt(rvals)) * rvecs.t();
  arma::mat diff = A - D;

  // Return result
  outcome = Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("rvals")    = rvals, 
                               Rcpp::Named("RI12_hat") = RI12_hat, 
                               Rcpp::Named("rvecs")    = rvecs);
  return outcome;   
}
```

### Test

Code:

```
set.seed(27)
A = matrix(round(rnorm(9),2), 3, 3)
A = A + t(A)

B = matrix(1, 3, 3); B[1,3] <- B[3,1] <- 0

magic_func(A, B)
```

Results:

```
$rvals
             [,1]
[1,] 2.414214e-08
[2,] 1.000000e+00
[3,] 2.414214e+00

$RI12_hat
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,]  1609.647 -2275.222  1608.647
[2,] -2275.222  3218.293 -2275.222
[3,]  1608.647 -2275.222  1609.647

$rvecs
           [,1]          [,2]      [,3]
[1,] -0.5000000 -7.071068e-01 0.5000000
[2,]  0.7071068 -7.077672e-16 0.7071068
[3,] -0.5000000  7.071068e-01 0.5000000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer. It is very useful.